# Install SWIG python bindings in install space

Tags: python, c++, ros-melodic, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're using SWIG to generate python bindings for some C++ classes. This works fine in the devel space (cmake below). However, I can't figure out how to change our cmake to also install the python modules in the install space in addition. I can change the destinations from CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX to CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX for `PYTHON_MODULE_DIR` which does what I want. However, then the modules are not available in the devel space anymore. So how can I properly install my modules to the install space?

I tried to add the install macro to the cmake below:

```
# Install 
install(TARGETS ${SWIG_MODULE_${target}_REAL_NAME}
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/python2.7/${DIST_DIR}/${PYTHON_PACKAGE_NAME}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/lib/python2.7/${DIST_DIR}/${PYTHON_PACKAGE_NAME}
)
```

But the corresponding files are not installed to the install space. I only get a relatively empty `__init__.py` and `__init__.pyc`. In the devel dist-package I have `__init__.py`, `_package_name.so`, `package_name.py`, `package_namePYTHON_wrap.cxx`.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/349875/install-swig-python-bindings-in-install-space/) by [prex](https://answers.ros.org/users/35086/prex/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2020-04-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The install from my post just installs the .so libraries. We needed to add this additional install rule:

```
 install(FILES ${SWIG_OUT_MODULE_DIR}/${MODULE_REAL_NAME}.py DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}/${CATKIN_PACKAGE_PYTHON_DESTINATION})
```

---

Originally posted by [prex](https://answers.ros.org/users/35086/prex/) with karma: 151 on 2020-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0